# git: How to delete local branches that do not exist in remote repo interactively branch by branch?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

There are many threads on this website that discuss the advantages of

```
git fetch --prune
```

and I really like it. But I locally have several branches that I do not want to push as well, which means that there are **branches which don't exist anymore** on remote repo and there are **branches which never existed there**. The former I want to delete, the latter I want to keep.
Of course git can not know which ones I want to keep. But I haven't found a (simple) interactive way to prune the branches branch by branch. I think about some simple mechanism like

```
rm -i
```

with which I can delete files via file by file in Linux shells

The only solution I can think of is to write a script to do a dry-run of git fetch prune, then ask me branch by branch to delete it manually with git branch delete command. Since I am not very good at writing safe and clean scripts (talking about Linux shells, not Windows here, but the general question is relevant for any OS where git is supported)

Yes, I could push all my local branches as well, but we already have a big number of branches (although we use the rebase and delete featurebranch mechanism) that clutter visual representations of our remote repo.

Any ideas appreciated, thanks in advance,

br

I tried:

```
git fetch --prune
```

and

```
git branch --delete
```

but git fetch prune deletes too many branches at once and git branch delete is rather slow and overly complicated to use for a bigger number of branches, since I need to know and delete all relevant branches manually.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your question: do you want to delete all local branches which are linked to a remote branch which doesn't exist anymore ?

Comment: I have local branches which do not exist anymore  on remote (these I want to delete) and have local branches which I never pushed (these I want to keep). git fetch prune unfortunately kills both and I did not find a command to allow me to decide branch by branch which ones I want to delete.

Comment: I have updated the title. I hope now it is more clear what I would like to know. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: What about deleting only the merged branches ? `git branch --merged main | grep -v '^[ *]*main$' | xargs git branch -d`

Comment: compact solution, thanks for the fast reply!
calling your snippet results in . `fatal: malformed object name main`. replacing it with `origin` and simply printing the output instead of deleting them immediately seems to provide an incomplete list, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a script
First you get all branches without upstream

Then if y is pressed you deleted it else you skip it

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for branch in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short) %(upstream)' refs/heads | awk '$2 !~/^refs\/remotes/'); do
    read  -n 1 -r -s -p "Are you sure you want to delete $branch? <y/N>" prompt
    if [[ $prompt == "y" ]]
    then
        echo -e "\r$branch \033[31mdeleting...\033[0m\033[0K"
        git branch -d $branch
        echo -e "$branch \033[31mdeleted\033[0m"
    else
        echo -e "\r$branch \033[32mkept\033[0m\033[0K"
    fi
done
```

`\r` is to go back to the line (erase the prompt question), delete actions are in red `\033[31m`, kept in green `\033[32m`

`\033[0m` to go back to normal color and `\033[0K` to erase remaining stuff on the line (from the prompt)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The interactive script is pretty nice. What I do not understand, though, is that the version of @LeGEC shows a completely different list of branches (no branch occurs in both lists). Do you have any idea why this might be? (sorry, I only have basic git knowledge and therefore do not completely understand the code of both of you.

Comment: The starting command (`git for-each-ref ... | awk '...'`) will list all branches that are now unlinked. This script just walks you through that list, and asks you to choose, branch by branch, whther you want to delete it or not.

Comment: Not sure which branches you want to interactively delete, with this script you will get all branches not linked to a remote branch (unlinked or neved linked). Is this what you ask for ?

Answer (score 2):

You want to make a difference between "the local branches that have an upstream branch" (which I'll call linked) and "the local branches that don't" (which I'll call unlinked).

The issue of running `git fetch --prune` is: this action also cleans up the existing links, so *after* running `git fetch --prune`, the linked branches that you want to delete will be seen as unlinked.

You would have to write a script that spots the branches *about to be pruned* without running `git fetch --prune`.

---

You can get an up to date list of branches that exist on the remote using `git ls-remote` :

```
git ls-remote origin "refs/heads/*"
# to get just the ref names:
git ls-remote origin "refs/heads/*" | awk '{ print $2 }'
# to print 'origin/[name]' instead of 'refs/heads/[name]':
git ls-remote origin "refs/heads/*" | awk '{ gsub("refs/heads/","origin/",$2); print $2 }'
```

There are several ways to get the list of your local branches that have an upstream branch, one would be to grep your way out of `git branch -vv`, for scripting purposes `git for-each-ref` is more indicated:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(upstream:short) %(refname:short)"` | grep "^origin/"
```

Combining these in a script to get the list of "linked branches that need to be deleted":

```
#!/bin/bash

list_remote_branches () {
    git ls-remote origin "refs/heads/*" | awk '{ gsub("refs/heads/","origin/",$2); print $2 }'
}

list_linked_local_branches () {
    git for-each-ref --format="%(upstream:short) %(refname:short)" | grep "^origin/"
}

# details:
#  - list local linked branches
#  - use 'grep -v' to remove from that list the ones that are still linked
#  - print only the local name
list_linked_local_branches | grep -v -f <(list_remote_branches) | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

---

You can either review the list of branches to delete, or use `xargs` feed it directly to `git branch --delete` :

```
# the '-r' option makes sure that nothing is run if the input is empty
./my_script.sh | xargs -r git branch --delete
```

Comment: ok, the first version of your script had a typo, but you updated that already (thanks). Just to be sure I understood your solution: The list of branches I get after calling that script is the list of branches which have been removed from remote, but still have a local copy (linked?). That list does not contain branches that were never pushed (unlinked?). Did I get that right?

Comment: @oneMoreCoder: yes, only linked branches will be listed. Remove the final `awk '{ print $2 }'` if you want to see that in a clearer way.

Comment: ok, then to delete these branches I copy that list and call git branch delete.
One more thing. I have two environments, one with git v2.2 and one with v2.39.0 the script only works with the latter version (get strange output and no list with it). To help those who find your solution, maybe one could mention that ("use current version of git, older won't work in all cases")

Comment: oh, feeding an input as a list of arguments is `xargs`. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @oneMoreCoder: 2.2 is pretty old, are you version locked on that system ? uprading the client side of git is basically painless

Comment: I have an official development environment provided by my company I need to use for building and stuff, where I am restricted to 2.2, but I use the program "git extensions" which uses 2.39 -> I can use your script. If one would really be thorough, one could mention that stuff with the older version, but that is just a cherry on top thingy.
But another thing: Ôrel posted a different approach, that results in a completely different list of branches in the same repo. I do not understand the difference between your approaches.